# PowerShell comparing multiple files

Tags: powershell, comparison, compareobject

In PowerShell there is a cmdlet Compare-Object for comparing two objects, but is there a way to compare 3 or more objects?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and the results you’d expect to see from it?

Comment: Comparing a list of **compare results** with a custom object list (a `csv` file??? -**please add more details!**). Anyways, this [`Join-Object script`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join)/[`Join-Object Module`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/JoinModule) (see also: [In Powershell, what's the best way to join two tables into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483110/1701026)) lets you *join* multiple object lists: `Import-Csv .\a.csv |Join (Import-Csv .\b.csv) |Join (Import-Csv .\c.csv)`